# Stuck in Simple Maths Recursive Issue Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on this Math recursive question.
What is needed to do is when I put in 0 to the console, it should display the answer then take that answer put into the equation and display the next answer, it should continuing doing this till the value indicate on the loop.

At the  moment this is my code:

```
const pw= (x) =>{
    sum = []
    for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
    let a = (x*x*x)
    sum+= ((4-a)/10)
        
    }
    return sum
    
}
```

So if I put in 0 the answer is 0.4, then it should take that answer (0.4) automatically put it through the code and return the next answer which is 0.3 and so on.

At the moment that's where i'm stuck i dont know how to automatically put the next vaule in.
Any guidance will be appreachiated.

```
console.log(pw(0))
(0.4)
(0.3)
(0.3973)
(0.3937287271683)
```

Comment: Your function needs to call itself to be recursive.  Inside pw, do your log.  At the end of pw decide if you want to recur, if you do, call pw with the next number.

Comment: what are the `(0.4)` `(0.3)` etc supposed to be?

Comment: by the way, what do you think adding a number to an Array will do?

Comment: also, the sequence you expect is not likely ... if x is 0.4, then `(4 - (x*x*x))/10` is not 0.3 - only if `x = 1` is `(4 - (x*x*x))/10` = `0.3`

Comment: 0.4, 0.3 are the answers that should be dispaly after each iteration

Comment: How? using what formula? because the code you wrote produces `0.4` when x is `0` but produces `0.3936` when x is `0.4` (assuming you want to do `(4 - (x*x*x))/10` for each iteration

Comment: I have generated an answer but stack is not letting me post it so i'm sending it here later will create an answer.

You can use a recursive function like this. This will get you your required answer.

```
function pw(num, times){
    const sum = (4 - (num ** 3)) / 10;
    console.log(sum);
    if(times<=1) return;
    else pw(sum, times-1);
}

pw(0, 5);
```

Comment: Yes this is where I'm gone wrong as in the array, it adds the previous number which shouldn't be doing. It should get the answer from 0, sshow the answer in the array then using that answer go through the equation and show the next answer. Should have used push method but at the moment not sure how to use the answer to redo the formula and get the next answer

Comment: @YashasMajmudar - that's a way to do it recursively for no reason :p however, it still doesn't produce the **expected** result

Comment: @Mahmud - your calculation won't produce `0.3` on the second iteration, it will produce `0.3936` ... so, unless you can explain why `0.4` becomes `0.3` then there's no fix that will help you

Comment: If you put 0.4 through the equation 0.393 is the next x value. Sorry my mistake

Comment: no, it's `0.3936`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must do it recursively, then you can do something like

```js
const pw = (x, sum=[]) => {
  if (sum.length > 4) {
    return sum;
  }
  let a = (4 - (x * x * x)) / 10;
  return pw(a, [...sum, a]);
}
console.log(pw(0))
```

Though, that's not very good, since if you pass in a second argument it goes boom - so, another recursive way

```js
const pw = input => {
  const fn = (x, sum=[]) => {
    if (sum.length > 4) {
      return sum;
    }
    let a = (4 - (x * x * x)) / 10;
    return fn(a, [...sum, a]);
  }
  return fn(input);
}
console.log(pw(0))
```

However, no need for recursion at all

```js
const pw = (x) => {
  const sum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    const a = (4 - (x * x * x)) / 10;
    sum.push(a);
    x = a;
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(pw(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function like this. This will get you your required answer.

```js
function pw(num, times){
    const sum = (4 - (num ** 3)) / 10;
    console.log(sum);
    if(times<=1) return;
    else pw(sum, times-1);
}

pw(0, 5);
```

### OR

If you want to use for loop.

```js
function pw(num, times){
    for(let i=0;i<times;i++){
        num = (4 - (num ** 3)) / 10;
        console.log(num);
    }
}

pw(0, 5);
```